# How to properly wait for an Android Service to be bounded to an Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, service, initialization, wait

I am developing an app in which several Activitis bound to a sevice once they become visible to the user. During start up, each Activity needs to:

- check some status flag of the service, based on which some UI elements are configured
- check wether an adapters is enabled whose reference is inside the service
- execute some functions of the Service

Since the applications should not get updates in the background, I bind to the service at onStart() and unbind at onStop(). I.e. in have something like this:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Intent(context, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
        bindService(intent, serviceCallback, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }
}
```

Now I want to perform the above mentionned actions inside onResume.

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    // check flags
    // check adapter status
    // excute functions of service
}
```

The problem is that binding to a service is asynchronous and I do not have a valid reference to the Service's binder inside onResume(). Consequently, the app will crash with a nullpointer exception.

**Approach 1: Using lateinit**

I tried solving this problem using the lateinit keyword. I.e. I define the reference to the binder as

```
private lateinit var myBinder: MyService.LocalBinder
```

Problem: I cannot guarantee that the binder is initialized as it is asynchronous. Thus, the app will crash.

**Approach 2: Waiting for callback in while loop**

In my service callback, I set a flag as follows:

```
val serviceCallback = object : ServiceConnection {

    override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
        myBinder = service as MyService.LocalBinder
        isServiceBounded = true
    }

    override fun onServiceDisconnected(arg0: ComponentName) {
        isServiceBounded = false
        myBinder = null
    }
}
```

Then inside onResume, I **block** the Activity until the flag is true

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    while(!isServiceBounded){
        // block and wait
    }
}
```

Problem: Doesn't work either. The app will stop responding and crashes.

**Approach 3: Using suspended functions and Kotlin coroutines**

A suspended function will not continue unless it has received a return value. This, I can use it to wait for an event. So I tried something like this:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        bindServiceAndWait(this@Activityname)
    }
}

suspend fun bindServiceAndWait(context: Context): Boolean{
    Intent(context, MyService::class.java).also { intent ->
        bindService(intent, serviceCallback, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }
    return isServiceBounded // This is the flag from the callback
}
```

Problem: This suspended function does not actually wait for the callback. It just returns the current value of isServiceBounded.

I found a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381902/wait-for-service-to-be-bound-using-coroutines), but I do not quite understand this solution as it has a global service callback (ServiceConnection) as well as a local one inside the suspended function. Also, I don't understand how to I could unbound in this provided example.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

you simply can't ensure that service will be bounded until `onResume` gets called. why won't you introduce flag `isResumed`, set it in `onResume` (unset in `onPause`) and line below check `if (isResumed && isServiceBounded)...`. yes, there is a chance that `isServiceBounded = false` in `onResume`, so same `if` check put in `onServiceConnected`

Comment: I don't see how that could help. If the service is not binded, then the code will skip the if-statement, thereby skipping the initialization.

Comment: but it will call `onServiceConnected` later, then `isResumed` flag will be set to `true` and this method call ensures that `Service` binded successfully (after `Activity` resume)